# Restore zoom/pan matrix on paging with ViewPager + Glide + PhotoView

Tags: android, android-glide, android-photoview

My use case is to have a ViewPager showing a series of PhotoView instances, where paging through the images should keep the last state of zoom and pan.

PhotoView instances are created by the PagerAdapter

```
public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(viewGroup.getContext());
    viewGroup.addView(photoView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    Glide.with(viewGroup.getContext())//
        .load(getImageUri(position))
        .into(photoView);
    return photoView;
}
```

I'm attaching a "OnMatrixChangedListener" to the PhotoView and storing the PhotoViewAttacher#mSuppMatrix.

The issue I have is to find the right moment to apply to stored mSuppMatrix.

- ViewPager#onPageSelected fires regardless of the ViewGroup state, ie. the PhotoView might still be drawing, or Glide might even still be loading
- Glide#RequestListener (onResourceReady) fires when the Drawable is ready, but apparently BEFORE running PhotoView#setImageDrawable
- Even overriding PhotoView#setImageDrawable and applying the mSuppMatrix after calling super.setImageDrawable is too early, as later a layout() call results in the PhotoViewAttacher running reset(), thus invalidating the mSuppMatrix

So given a target "mSuppMatrix " holding zoom/pan information, and using the combo of ViewPager + PhotoView + Glide, what is the best listener/event handler to apply the mSuppMatrix ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a single event indicating the state I'm looking for. Instead, I'm using a combination of:

- Glide RequestListener#onResourceReady()
- View.OnLayoutChangeListener#onLayoutChange()

such that the first call to onLayoutChange() **after** the Glide resource is ready is the triggering one.